# Delete from a table after checking if it exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check if a table exists before deleting a row from it in sql. I have tried several things off the internet and this seems to come up the most, but it is not working.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('mytable', 'N') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id= :user_id
END
```

I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF OBJECT_ID('we_image_gallery', 'U') IS NOT NULL DELETE FROM mytable' at line 1
```

I need a solution that uses only the current database and I can count on when the script is ported to multiple systems.

Edit: This query is ran by PHP PDO. Beings none of the answers seem to working is it possible there is a settings in my pdo or sql server that's causing the issue?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: That actually raises another question. Is it better to make a extra table that stores what tables have been created (by installing a different mix of add ons on different sights) and use that to check for tables, or stay with my current system of checking for the table with a sql statement.

Comment: Your current system is terrible, but your proposed alternative is just as bad. You should know what tables exist in your database; it should not be a matter of guesswork.

Comment: This only becomes a problem if the add on file is uploaded but the set up is not ran. I know what is installed, but I can't count on other users of my system to not do this. so I'm just trying to get a safety net.

Comment: Just fix your design; that's what I'd do, anyway

Comment: I haven't got time to test the theory or give a full answer here, so I'll just comment. BEGIN..END is a T-SQL control structure, which I'd say is probably taboo in PHP PDOs.  You can't have multiple statements in PDOs, I don't see why control structures would be any different. I would try doing this in two steps - step 1) issue a select statement against the information schema, step 2) if the row count of the previous statement is > 0, then execute your delete statement.

Comment: @e_i_pi you are right. that was the problem. Thank you. now, I could check using a select statement, or I can just ignore the error the delete statement gets. but would that cause any issues or make any security holes?

Comment: I would put the check in, that seems like a good design to me. For the people who have said this problem points to bad design, it's a necessary approach in upgrading a database for an application that didn't follow best practice in the first place. I've had to do this in a real world scenario where we had disparate branched patches to an app and wanted to bring every deployed instance into line with a new version

Comment: This isn't so much a bad design as me trouble shooting. Because I can;t predict what user's of the system may do I need to a solution to catch errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Exists statement to delete data from table:

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Your_table WHERE user_id = user_id)
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Your_table WHERE user_id= user_id
END

Delete table from database :

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =    
    'TheSchema' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable')
BEGIN
    --Your delete statement
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**  for any table by giving table name in **where clause** and If that table exist then you can perform your required operation as below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tbl_User')
BEGIN
--If table exist you can perform your operation here
--  DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id= :user_id
 Print 'Table Exists'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support `IF` statements in the dynamic SQL parser. You can use [flow-control statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-statements.html) like that only in the body of stored routines or triggers.

I would suggest one of two strategies here. One option is to simply *try* a statement like DELETE, but check for errors. Or catch the exception if you have enabled PDO exceptions.

```
try {
    $pdo->exec("DELETE ...");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log("SQL statement on $mytable failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

> SQL statement on mytable failed: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.mytable' doesn't exist

Another strategy would be to query for the table, and do something if it does/doesn't exist.

```
try {
        $stmt = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'mytable'");
        if (!$stmt->fetchColumn()) {
                error_log("No such table 'mytable'");
        }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "SQL statement failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```